# Microsoft Graph API permissions changes not propagating using Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We used Azure AD to setup an app which allows gives trust/permissions to an MSGraph Office account. The permissions were not setup to allow the code to programmatically send a email on the users behalf when they sign up.

Some beta users started using the service. Then after some time we changed the permissions in Azure AD to give permissions to allow to send emails on behalf of the user.

Since then new users can send emails, but beta and older users still have not got these permissions. The token expiration I believe is set to 3 days and its been a lot longer than that. Is there a way to force the permissions to propagate to all users?

If not, is there somewhere where beta users can unsubscribe from the app (kind of like you can with playstore apps) and then reassign permissions when they login again?

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but did you try the "Grant Permissions" button? It states: "Do you want to grant the permissions below for <API Name> for all accounts in current directory? This action will update any existing permissions this application already has to match what is listed below." It is right next to the "+ Add" permission button.

Comment: @Wiz we granted permissions, everytime there was a change. Oddly the button does what it says, it says for "your account" however it grants to the application. Is there anyway I can goto say office.portal.com and unsubscribe from the app? Surely Microsoft must have provided users the ability to unlink their app/product from msgraph permissions if they wont want msgraph linked anymore?

Comment: Not sure if this works with Azure AD or not, but I had this link saved in my notes: https://account.live.com/consent/Manage

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to have already occurred but, if it's taking too long, you *can* force the user to re-consent to the permision by adding [`prompt=consent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) to your inital OAuth URI:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?{parmas}&prompt=consent
```

Comment: We currently have 2 urls to connect, could I add that query param to one of these? https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 and https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: `graph.microsoft.com` is the Graph API and while it _consumes_ the token, it has no involvment with issuing them. `login.microsoftonline.com` on the other hand authenicates and issues tokens from your AAD instance. This is the OAuth authorization endpoint you want to add the `prompt` query param too.

Comment: reason I ask is my login url above does not look like it has oauth2 in it, will this prompt param still work with the well-known url?

Comment: That url only retrieves the [endpoint configuration settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document). Elsewhere in your workflow will be the actual [redirect to the OAuth `/authorize` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request). It's the redirect that you need to add this param to.